# How to remove all 1 from given list in C# program?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list

I have a `List<int>` that contains multiple `1` values, and I want to remove all of them. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7 };

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == 1)
    {      
        numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: iterate the list in the reverse order, or else you will have issues after itens are removed

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be much clearer about what you're trying to achieve. (It's not clear why you're using the arrays tag when you're asking about a list, not an array, for one thing...)

Comment: You could just use [`List.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Depends on how you are going to consume the result. If you need a list, the `List.Removeall` will work, but if you are OK to pass an IEnumerable to another method then `numbers.Where(x => x != 1)` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-6.0) method, you can specify a predicate which will be called for each item in the list. If it returns `true`, that item will be removed.

For example:

`numbers.RemoveAll(n => n == 1)`

Comment: Just make sure that the `match` predicate will never throw, otherwise the list [might get corrupted](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66255 "Not documented that the List<T>.RemoveAll method can corrupt the list").